# 413 Uploading large files to s3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, filesystems

I'm trying to upload some large files > 200MB through a form input to S3, but I seem to be getting `413 Request Entity Too Large`. Do I have to specifically configure my webserver to handle larger files or can I chunk the file somehow?

Comment: Did you check the value of `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` ?

Comment: @LucaStucchi Yes, I changed it in the project, the `php.ini` file, and the nginx configuration file. However, I would prefer to chunk it up anyway so that it's not eating up all the ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to upload big files you should use streams. Here’s the code to do it:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($targetFile, fopen($sourceFile, 'r+'));
```

PHP will only require a few MB of RAM even if you upload a file of several GB.

Source: https://murze.be/2015/07/upload-large-files-to-s3-using-laravel-5/

See Lrvl5 doc for usage and config of Storage :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but I still seem to get a `413`. Do I still need to change the max upload size? And if so, where else should I change this? I've updated the php.ini and nginx config file to support larger files but it doesn't seem to care. :/

Comment: Didn't manage to get it working locally but jumped through a few hoops and managed to change the settings on the hosted server and got it working.

Comment: Nice one. Did you try comparing `nginx.conf`s between dev/test?

Comment: The server is hosted on Heroku and running Apache, so I couldn't do that unfortunately. Hehe.